# Material UI Grid component Fill second column to end of container

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using material UI's Grid component and making use of the `auto` property for the first column

so I have

```
<Grid container className={classes.borderclass}>
   <Grid item xs={"auto"}>
      <Items />
    </Grid>
   <Grid item xs={10}>
      <Content />
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

However this will not fill the entire container but I do not seem to see an option for remainder in the sizes.
I have looked into css `calc` option however I do not see a way to get the size of the auto column in react to compare against the div

any suggestions even if it is not material ui will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the Material-UI demo, they have a working example that shows the auto property in action. So, as the example depicted [here](https://material-ui.com/layout/grid/#auto-layout), you don't need to specify the `auto` keyword. Do just this:

```
<Grid container className={classes.borderclass}>
   <Grid item xs>
      <Items />
    </Grid>
   <Grid item xs={10}>
      <Content />
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```